# How to use 'Consolas' as the coding font

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I would like to change the font for code edition in a Squeak 4.3 image on windows OS, to use if possible the consolas font.

I found nothing in the preferences browser to do that easily. That [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574873/how-can-i-easily-change-to-native-fonts-in-smalltalk-squeak-pharo) looked perfect, but none of the answers work in my case.

For example on the line

```
font := LogicalFont familyName: 'Bitmap DejaVu Sans' pointSize: 10.
```

It fails on the `LogicalFont`: I get the popup that allows to fix a missing class/variable.

> Unknown variable: LogicalFont please correct, or cancel: [...]

Is that solution not suitable for Squeak 4.3, or am I missing some package?

**EDIT**: as often, I am finding some answer elements *after* the question has been posted on SO:

> I found nothing in the preferences browser to do that easily.

Because the setting is not accessible via the Preference Browser, but via the World menu -> Appearance -> System fonts -> code font.

But I only see a handful of fonts available (beside ComicSans and BitstreamVera), but no Consolas. I do have the preference `Offer native fonts` enabled, though...

**Second Edit**: given the answer of Igor Stasenko, I found on SqueakSource a mention of [FreeTypePlus](http://www.squeaksource.com/@F_D5WfXcpOnk3kgI/eKYxPXFN) that seems the most recent (not often easy for a beginner to find out how to install new software on Squeak, also it seems that Squeak has slowed down since 2006/2007 and some items mentioned in the [Swiki](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak) are down now...)

So I added on Monticello

```
MCHttpRepository
    location: 'http://www.squeaksource.com/FreeTypePlus'
    user: ''
    password: ''
```

And installed `FreeType`, `FreeTypeSubPixelAntiAliasing` and `PinesoftEnhancementsForFreetype`. Now I can see my ttf system fonts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, Squeak doesn't includes Freetype support by default.

You may try Pharo, where Freetype is included by default. http://www.pharo-project.org/home

Or you can try to install Freetype package in Squeak & download freetype plugin for VM.

Comment: Before going on Pharo, I would like to train myself on Squeak. I installed a package named `FreeType` from `FreeTypePlus` repository and it seems OK (see my edit). Thanks.